# SQL Server binary value in dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need binary value in dynamic SQL but I am getting an error

> The data types nvarchar and binary are incompatible in the add operator

I need help.

```
DECLARE @MaxSeqValue binary(10)=NULL
DECLARE @script varchar(max)

-- I have incremental binary values in my table,which I can sort it.
SELECT 
    @MaxSeqValue = MAX(seqvalue) 
FROM [dbr].[DBA_CDClog]-- this my log table
WHERE TableName = @TableName2

set @script = 'Select seq value, tablename
               from table X
               where SeqValue >'+@MaxSeqValue+'
'
```

Comment: Parameterise it and use `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast @MaxSeqValue to nvarchar.

```
set @script ='
Select seq value,
tablename
from table X
where SeqValue >' + cast(@MaxSeqValue as nvarchar(max))
```

Comment: Here is the result unfortuantely some strange character I got:-( 'WHERE  SeqValue >굗'      the output looks like chinese.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is worked for me. CAST option didnt workout.

```
WHERE  SeqValue >0x'+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@MaxSeqValue,2)+'
```